# Android Studio not recognizing String

Tags: java, android, android-studio, visual-glitch

I've encountered a weird glitch in Android Studio: [image: Android studio String glitch]

As you can see it thinks that it is an error:

```
'class' or 'interface' expected
```

But it runs and build just fine, so is this just a visual glitch or can it have any effect during compiling?

I'm running Android Studio 0.5.8 for Mac

Things I've tried so far:

- Restart Android Studio
- Restart MacBook
- Invalidate caches and restart
- tried other strings (like "en-US" this result in the same effect)

If I use a string through the resources the glitch isn't visible (which it will be eventually, I'm just curious why this is happening)

Comment: are you 100% that the " from the first string are equals to the ones from the "en" string? I had some copy&paste issues where there was wrong but identically looking symbols where used...

Comment: Yeah I'm sure. Even when I copy&paste the " from the first string to the second string it still shows up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ and Android Studio have the ability to take string parameters and treat the strings as being in another language. For example, if you have a method that takes a string that's HTML, if you tell the IDE about it, it can give you syntax highlighting and content assist with the HTML in that string.

I think you've inadvertently set this string as being treated as Java, and it's giving you the Java syntax errors on it. You need to un-set that setting. Select the text, bring up the Search Action feature (on Mac it's <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>). In the search box that comes up, search for Un-inject Language/Reference, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of IDE, showing search for the command to uninject language/reference]

Comment: @chappie112 then what ?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
httpReqquest.addHeader("Accept-Language","en-US");
```

Comment: That doesn't matter it still gives the impression that it is an error on "en-US". (I also tried "random-string" but it gives the same error)

Comment: check on your imports

Comment: My import are just fine, as I said it works perfectly fine(I think) I suspect it is just a visual-glitch but I need to be certain of this.

Answer (score -1):

Since Android Studio is a bit raw, you can face the "glitches" in many different ways. They're annoying but don't affect the result, as you said. However, I personally don't think that we should endure the inconveniences (even if the Studio costs nothing).

I see a couple of solutions:

1. Continue with AS and ignore these weird things, hoping they will release a robust software once
2. Or, to migrate to IntelliJ IDEA as I did. The procedure is pricey but it's worth it.